# Is it consistent for $P(\mathbb{N})$ to be present in a low layer of the Constructible Universe?

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, peano-axioms, reverse-math

$ZF+V=L$ implies that $P(\mathbb{N})$, the power set of the set of natural numbers, is a subset of $L_{\omega_1}$.  But my question is, is it consistent with $ZF$ if $P(\mathbb{N})$ is a subset of $L_{\omega+1}$, i.e. the only subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are arithmetical sets?  Most mathematicians would definitely think it’s a false statement, but is it inconsistent with either $ZF$ or $ZFC$?

The reason I ask is that this is basically Bertrand Russell’s Axiom of Reducibility.

Comment: If $L$ is the smallest inner model, how can that even be possible?

Comment: @AsafKaragila What does $L$ being the smallest inner model have to do with anything?

Comment: Any subsets of $\Bbb N$ in $L$ are also subsets of $\Bbb N$ in the actual universe. If $L$ cannot capture all the subsets of $\Bbb N$ in the first transfinite step of the constructible hierarchy, what hope do larger class-models have?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Elaborating on Asaf's comment: if $M$ is a model of ZF, then $L^M$ is a model of ZF + V=L. So $L^M$ contains a real $r$ which $L^M$ thinks is not in $(L_{\omega+1})^M$. But clearly $r\in M$, and by absoluteness $M$ doesn't think $r\in (L_{\omega+1})^M$ either. So for any model $M$ of ZF, there is an $r\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^M$ with $r\not\in (L_{\omega+1})^M$. (And the same argument works for any $\gamma<\omega_1^M$.)

Comment: For all "small" countable ordinals $\alpha$ (certainly for all $\alpha<\varepsilon_0$, for instance, in particular for $\alpha=\omega+1$) you can exhibit explicit sets of natural numbers that are in $L$ but first appear at $L_{\alpha+1}$, which gives you an explicit counterexample to the claim that $\mathcal P(\omega)\subset L_\alpha$.

Comment: Do the answers below clarify the issue? If not, what remaining questions do you have?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Your answer did clarify the issue, thanks.  I think the problem is that I didn’t ask the question I really intended to ask.  Now I posted the question I should have asked in the first place: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3247203/71829

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me compile my comments into an answer. I'll first explain (elaborating on Asaf's comment) why every model of ZF contains (things it thinks are) sets of naturals which (it thinks) have $L$-rank arbitrarily high below $\omega_1$. Then I'll talk about the relevant axiomatic strength.

---

If $M$ is a model of ZF, then $L^M$ is a model of ZF + V=L. So $L^M$ contains a real $r$ which $L^M$ thinks is not in $(L_{\omega+1})^M$. But clearly $r\in M$, and by absoluteness $M$ doesn't think $r\in (L_{\omega+1})^M$ either. So for any model $M$ of ZF, there is an $r\in \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})^M$ with $r\not\in (L_{\omega+1})^M$.

And the same argument works for any $\gamma<\omega_1^M$: if $\gamma<(\omega_1)^{L^M}$ then $L^M$ has a real $r$ it thinks has $L$-rank $>\gamma$, and this lifts to $M$.

---

Alright, so now let's talk about better logical strength bounds.

First, let me give an argument which gives a non-optimal upper bound but is rather elementary. Let $\mathcal{W}$ be the set of (indices of) computable linear orders without descending sequences. Any reasonable set theory at all (by far less than Z or KP or similar) proves that *if $\mathcal{W}$ exists* then it is non-arithmetic *(indeed, RCA$_0$ proves this, appropriately phrased!)*. In particular, by Separation Zermelo set theory proves that there is a non-arithmetic set.

Unfortunately, the existence of $\mathcal{W}$ has rather high axiomatic strength; KP + Inf, for example, *doesn't* prove it exists. To bring things down we need to do some model theory. Inside any model of a tiny fragment of set theory - both Z and KP are already more than enough - truth *for set-sized structures* is definable (uniformly in the structure, even). Roughly speaking, a sentence $\varphi$ is true in $\mathcal{M}$ if there exists a family $\mathbb{F}$ of functions from finite powers of $\mathcal{M}$ to $\mathcal{M}$ which serve as Skolem functions for $\varphi$. This definition takes place (essentially) in $(\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{M}))^{<\omega}$, not in $\mathcal{M}$ itself, so we don't run up against Tarski here.

- This definition is just a piece of *language*; where the theory comes in is showing that $(i)$ for all $\mathcal{M}$ and $\varphi$ either $\mathcal{M}\models\varphi$ or $\mathcal{M}\models\neg\varphi$ and $(ii)$ $Th(\mathcal{M})$ (=$\{\varphi: \mathcal{M}\models\varphi\}$) exists.

Now the proof of Tarski's undefinability theorem goes through in a very very tiny fragment of ZFC, and so in particular we have that the theory of the natural numbers (as a semiring) is not arithmetic.

Answer (score 7):

No: $L_\alpha$ is countable for any countable $\alpha$, so it cannot contain all of $P(\mathbb{N})$.

Comment: Do you know what exact axioms are used to prove that $L_{\omega+1}$ is countable?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Few enough that it doesn't seem a good question. In particular, note that there's an obvious surjection from $\omega\times L_\omega$ to $L_{\omega+1}$ which you can define as long as you can talk about theories of structures, and the Ackermann interpretation gives an as-concrete-as-imaginable bijection between $L_\omega$ and $\omega$. In particular, KP + infinity is already overkill.

Comment: The body of your question, though, rephrases things even more simply: you ask whether it's consistent that every set of naturals is arithmetic. Well, it's easy to show that if the theory of $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$ exists, then it's not arithmetic, so again as soon as you can talk about the set of natural numbers and can talk about theories of structures that's already too much. So it's really impossible to escape this without killing so much of set theory that I'm not sure what's left.

Comment: @NoahSchweber What about Zermelo set theory, i.e. ZF without replacement?  Does that suffice that $P(\mathbb{N}$ contains things other than arithmetical subsets?  And what do you mean by “if the theory of $(ℕ;+,×)$ exists, then it's not arithmetic”?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan I'm not sure what your last question means. The theory of $(\mathbb{N}; +,\times)$ is the set of Godel numbers of sentences $\varphi$ such that $(\mathbb{N}; +,\times)\models\varphi$. This is definable in set theory (indeed, we can uniformly define truth of *set-sized* structures), and we can prove that, if it exists, it's not arithmetic.

Comment: And yes, Zermelo set theory is again *far more* than is necessary. It will help to first consider the example of $\omega$-models for simplicity (so we don't have to think about nonstandard sentences). The point is that for every sentence of arithmetic $\varphi$, there is an *arithmetic* witness (= appropriate family of Skolem functions, or similar) to the truth of $\varphi$ or the truth of $\neg\varphi$; so when we apply Separation to get the set of sentences true in $\mathbb{N}$, we in fact get a complete consistent theory. It's not hard now to run the usual argument that it's not arithmetic.

Comment: Here's a way to think about things which is actually more axiomatically complicated but perhaps less intuitively complicated: look at the set $\mathcal{W}$ of computable well-orderings without descending sequences. This exists by Z (separation), but it's not hard to show (in RCA$_0$, even) that this set isn't arithmetic. Now this is axiomatically harder - KP + Inf alone does *not* prove that $\mathcal{W}$ exists - but it doesn't involve any model-theoretic ideas.