# What subsystem of set theory proves the first Constructible Universe gap occurs late?

Tags: logic, set-theory, reverse-math

A gap in the constructible universe $L$ occurs at an ordinal $\beta$ if $L_\beta\cap P(\mathbb{N})=L_{\beta+1}\cap P(\mathbb{N})$.  Now $ZFC$ implies that the first gap in the constructible universe occurs at a large nonrecursive ordinal $\beta_0$, known as the ordinal of ramified analysis.  But I’m wondering what it takes to prove that the first gap doesn’t occur much earlier, and that too a longer gap.

My question is, what is the weakest subsystem of $ZFC$ that proves that $L_{\omega+1}\cap P(\mathbb{N})\neq L_{\omega+\omega}\cap P(\mathbb{N})$?  That is, that a gap in the constructible universe of a length $\omega$ does not occur at $\omega+1$.  Or to put it another way, that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $(L_{\omega+n}-L_{\omega+1})\cap P(\mathbb{N})\neq\varnothing$.

Would Kripke-Platek Set Theory, Zermelo Set Theory, or something weaker suffice?  In any case, the motivation of my question is that this is basically the negation of Bertrand Russell’s Axiom of Reducibility.

Comment: Are you going to consider set theories formulated in a logic that can't derive the Law of the Excluded Middle?

Comment: @DerekElkins No, I’m not.

Comment: Okay, then that's what the tag [tag:constructive-mathematics] refers to, not to the constuctible universe.

Comment: @DerekElkins Intuitionistic logic is just one small aspect of constructive mathematics.  The subject of the question is related to another topic in constructive mathematics, namely [predicativity](https://math.stanford.edu/~feferman/papers/predicativity.pdf) and impredicativity.  That’s why it references the ordinal of ramified analysis and Russell’s axiom of reducibility.

Comment: Predicativity is a somewhat orthogonal concern. You can have constructive and non-constructive predicative systems. Your very reference states: "Since, as I have argued, Poincare did not go that far, he can be considered to be laying out a middle ground between the constructivists and the set-theoretical platonist[.]" This is consistent with my experience with people who identify as predicativists: they are usually not also constructivists though they may occasionally use some constructive logics. Just because it's weaker than traditional foundations doesn't mean it's constructive.

Comment: @DerekElkins This is a moot point now that the tag has been removed, but for the record I think predicativism is a species of constructivism. Constructivism is the philosophy that mathematical objects are a construction of the human mind, and that is the motivation of predicativist concerns about only constructing mathematical objects out of objects you’ve already constructed. Now it’s true some people associated with predicativity aren’t constructivists, but that’s because they subscribe to Feferman’s “predicativity given the natural numbers” rather than Edward Nelson-style full predicativity

Comment: Somewhat off-topic but you might find it interesting. Categorical semantics gives *a* [nice story for the semantics](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/pretopos#definitions) and (via [internal logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic)) the logics of systems where we can "toggle" each of Finitism, Constructivism, and Predicativity independently albeit from the perspective of a roughly traditional meta-language. Nelson accepts LEM in *Predicative Arithmetic* and even discusses constructive connectives. Forcing him into the above framework would suggest he was working in a Boolean pretopos.

Comment: @DerekElkins Thanks, I’ll look into it.